# Multiple sql server versions on the same PC

Tags: sql-server

For several reasons , I need to install several sql server versions on the same Pc : 2005 , 2008 , 2008 R2 , 2012 , 2014,2016.
I've read somewhere that this can be done using different instance names for each sql version. But the problem is that every time i try to install a higher versions , is trying to upgrade the existing version and not to install as a new version keeping the old version untouched.

How can i do this scenario ?
Thank you !

Comment: I would not do it. I would change the reasons. Or I would do a workaround and install as many VMs on the PC as you want to have SQL Servers and install 1 SQL on 1 VM. And use port forwarding from the PC to different ports and achieve that all SQL Servers would appear to be on the same address but on different ports.

Comment: Sorry , this is not what i'm asking for. I need to install on the same Pc , not on VM.

Comment: that's why I added a comment not an answer ;) ok. but it would appear as on the same pc because you would use the host's IP :) - but I get your point. will see if you get a solution for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct this can be done using named instances, but only for the database engine. The shared features will be upgraded.

Ensure you do not have any default instances of SQL installed (that means SQL installs that don't have a named instance). These are designed only to be used when no other SQL version is installed on the host, these will block Port 1433. This was the usual configuration for SQL 2000 & 2005. With named instances each instance has a dynamic(random) port allocated, the SQL Browser sits on port 1433 and redirects the SQL connection to the correct port for the named instance.

SQL 2005 used a nice simple installer. With the introduction of SQL 2008 new additional software was required such as Power Shell and .NET. This required a new SQL installer which was a bit confusing and rough around the edges. Thankfully the SQL installers improved with each version. I suspect your trouble will probably be mainly with the 2008 installer.

Start with the lowest SQL version first and work your way up.

Install only the database engine and I recommend you name your instances such as MYPC\SQL2005, MYPC\SQL2008, MYPC\SQL2008R2 etc.

You will have to skip lots of compatibility warnings. Using Microsoft Update to install the SQL Service Packs and hot fixes should fix most of these compatibility issues after installation.

Don't install Management Studio until the end and use the new standalone SQL Management Studio from [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255)

When you use the new SQL 2008 and above installer you need to choose **Installation** from the left hand side. Then **New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation**. Followed by **Perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008**. You then need to check the box for **Database Engine Services**. Then name your instance and continue.

Repeat this for each version.

Obviously with all these services running it is going to create a load on the system. If you are using this for intermittent testing purpose I would recommend configuring the SQL services to manual startup type. Install [SQL 2005 Service Manager](http://sql2005srvcmngr.codeplex.com/) which will allow you to quickly startup a SQL Service when required from the system tray. (Despite the name it will allow you to start or stop any version of SQL)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But please can you explain to me what i will loose when shared features are upgraded ? I mean , my scenario is just to use different databases in different sql server version  with my program in vb.net. will i be able to do this ? And also can i just install only the database engine for all sql server versions and at the end the Management studio ? Can i connect to different versions with the same management studio ? Thank you !

Comment: I don't know what you will lose when shared features are upgraded, all I can say I have never noticed anything that stops the instances from appearing as completely independent. Yes you can use each different database with your program. Yes install only the database engine and then finally management studio, it can connect to any version so it is best to have the latest. That is why Microsoft separated Management Studio from the SQL Installer last year as it doesn't make sense to have the Management Studio version tied to the database engine installer.